# Progressively build a MongoDB aggregation based on dynamic criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

In a Java SpringBoot application that uses MongoDB, we store documents with the following structure:

```json
{
  "_id": "String",
  "projects": [
    {
      "experienceId": "String",
      "projectName": "String",
      "projectType": "String",
      "projectAddress": "String",
      "isSubsidy": "Boolean",
      "priceBase": "Double",
      "builder": "String",
      "pricesFrom": "Double",
      "city": "String"
    }
  ],
  "modificationDate": "Long"
}
```

We need to find the document matching an `_id,` and then modify the `projects` array (preferably through the Mongo Engine) according to the certain conditions, which are consolidated into a `ParameterFilter` object that looks like this:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ParameterFilter {
    private List<String> builder;
    private List<String> city;
    private Boolean isSubsidy;
    private Double priceFromMin;
    private Double priceFromMax;
}
```

So, for example, we need to filter the `projects` array so that we only get the objects whose `city` matches the `city` in ParameterFilter. **Since this object is built using query parameters in a handler, some of its attributes may be `null`**.

In order to do so, we have devised the following method inside our Repository class:

```java
@Override
    public Mono<TransformSharePointInformation> findByFilters(String id, ParameterFilter parameterFilter) {

    // Finds the document by ID
        MatchOperation documentMatchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));

    // Builds the projection operations to perform on the matched document
        ProjectionOperation projectFilteringProjection = Aggregation.project("projects");
        
    if (Objects.nonNull(parameterFilter.getIsSubsidy())) {
            projectFilteringProjection
                    .and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("projects")
                            .as("project")
                            .by(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("$$project.isSubsidy")
                                    .equalToValue(parameterFilter.getIsSubsidy())))
                    .as("projects");
        }
        
        // Append additional projection operations, depending on 'parameterFilters'

        TypedAggregation<SharePointInformationDocument> typedAggregation = new TypedAggregation<>(SharePointInformationDocument.class, documentMatchOperation, projectFilteringProjection);

        return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(typedAggregation, SharePointInformationDocument.class)
                .map(sharePointInformationDocument -> mapper.map(sharePointInformationDocument, TransformSharePointInformation.class)).next();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this setup is returning the unmodified `projects` array, so the filter doesn´t work. However, if the `projectFilteringProjection` is built as follows:

```
     ProjectionOperation projectFilteringProjection = Aggregation.project()
                .and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("projects")
                        .as("project")
                        .by(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("$$project.isSubsidy")
                                .equalToValue(parameterFilter.getIsSubsidy())))
                .as("projects");
```

The projection actually works, but then we have no way to *conditionally append additional projection operations based on `parameterFilter`*.

Is there a way to build the a `ProjectionOperation` step by step?